# VBA code deletes it's own sheet, leaving a "ghost" sheet behind

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet with VBA code to call a userform.  When I run that userform one of the instructions is to delete the sheet (but since it called the userform in the first place I suspect the code on that sheet is still running).  That ends up leaving a "ghost" sheet behind in the VBA Microsoft Excel Objects list.  You can't remove these sheets as the option is greyed out.  As a result I am accumulating a large amount of "ghost" sheets.

[screenshot](http://i1120.photobucket.com/albums/l490/oshoguno/2014-10-0907_59_14-MicrosoftVisualBasicforApplications-MaintenanceWCR642Rxlsm.jpg).

Code on the sheet:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call Show_UserForm
End Sub
```

Any advice or help around this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The "ghost" sheets that are left behind are just the code for the object.

I'm not sure what the effect would be since you are deleting the sheet that the routine was called from, but you can delete these ghost sheets using the `ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("XXX").Delete` method where `XXX` is the `(name)` of the object.

Comment: So I can use this command with a _BeforeClose sub correct?  What would be a good way to delete these ghost sheets automatically?  (code to determine if the sheet is a ghost or not).
When I get a chance to try your method I will let you know and mark my post as answered.

Thanks!

Comment: It didn't work for me as is.

    Private Sub test()
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Sheet10").Delete
    End Sub

Do I need to define something?  When I type it out and put the period in I get the list of options and delete is not one of them.

Comment: It probably won't let you do that since the code inside the sheet is still running.  What version of excel are you using?

Comment: 2010, the workbook has been saved, closed and re-opened.

Comment: I can't seem to remove any vba sheets from this workbook whether they exist or not (you can tell the difference from the icon beside the name in the picture).  These sheets were brought over by another workbook using activesheet.move if that makes any difference.  Someone uses the first workbook to make a request and that worksheet is moved to this workbook for someone else to update and delete.  Everything works but I am unable to get rid of the vba objects code for the sheets.

Comment: What happens if you run `Sheet10.Delete` in the immediate window?

Comment: If you mean without the quotes, automation error and catastrophic error.  If you mean exactly as you typed it, I get a method or data member not found error.

Comment: I can't replicate your situation, so it's difficult for me to help.
Try `ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove("Sheet10")` in the immediate window.

Comment: If you are interested I can send you a copy of the workbook.  I'm not asking you to find a fix for me, just offering if it intrigues you.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem; hence I thought I’d post, in case helpful.  The sheets which I deleted from an excel were existing as objects and I wasn’t able to delete the sheets manually. When I checked the properties, I saw that the property ‘Visible’ is set to 2 (xlSheetVeryHidden). I changed them to -1 and then I was able to delete all of them.  I used the below code to delete the sheets.

However,I am not sure what caused the sheets to be invisible. There was a reference link in the first sheet of my excel to the deleted pages, which might have caused this.

```
Sub deleteGhosts()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim tabname As String

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    For Each Sheet In wb.Worksheets
        tabname = Sheet.Name
        If wb.Worksheets(tabname).Visible = 2 Then
            MsgBox "Deleting " + tabname
            wb.Worksheets(tabname).Visible = -1
            wb.Worksheets(tabname).Delete
        End If
    Next Sheet

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, my sheets are not very hidden.  Actually I don't know what they are but when the sheet gets deleted it changes whatever is left behind.  The properties change dramatically.  You can see the difference in the two images.

!http://i1120.photobucket.com/albums/l490/oshoguno/2014-10-3012_28_00-MicrosoftVisualBasicforApplications-MaintenanceWCR_Lexus_Frontxlsm-She.jpg

!http://i1120.photobucket.com/albums/l490/oshoguno/2014-10-3012_28_46-MicrosoftVisualBasicforApplications-MaintenanceWCR_Lexus_Frontxlsm-She.jpg